Reference on asymptotic expansion of Dawson integral
The wiki and several posts claim that the Dawson integral has the following asymptotic expansion for large (real) $x$,
$$
e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{y^2}dy \sim \frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x^3}+\frac{3}{8x^5}+\cdots
$$
I was not able to find this particular formula in the standard reference: Handbook of Mathematical Function. Could you kindly point out a reference where the formula has been proved?

I couldn't find any references, but it follows from $F(x) =  - \frac{{\rm i}}{2}\sqrt \pi  {\rm e}^{ - x^2 } (1 - {\mathop{\rm erfc}\nolimits} ({\rm i}x))$ and $(7.12.1)$. I can also post a quick derivation using Watson's lemma if it helps.

@Gary That would be very helpful if you could elaborate the details further.

https://www.scielo.org.mx/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0188-62662019000100175    could be interesting to you

Here is a simple derivation using Watson's lemma, assuming $x>0$. To begin, note that
$$
{\rm e}^{ - x^2 } \int_0^x {{\rm e}^{y^2 } {\rm d}y}\; \mathop  = \limits^{y = xt} \;x\int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{ - x^2 (1 - t^2 )} {\rm d}t}\; \mathop  = \limits^{t = \sqrt {1 - s} } \;\frac{x}{2}\int_0^1 {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - x^2 s} }}{{\sqrt {1 - s} }}{\rm d}s} .
$$
We now consider the integral over the interval $[1/2,1]$:
$$
0 \le \int_{1/2}^1 {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - x^2 s} }}{{\sqrt {1 - s} }}{\rm d}s}  \le {\rm e}^{ - x^2 /2} \int_{1/2}^1 {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - s} }}{\rm d}s}  = \sqrt 2 \,{\rm e}^{ - x^2 /2}  = \mathcal{O}({\rm e}^{ - x^2 /2} ).
$$
Thus, we can write
$$
{\rm e}^{ - x^2 } \int_0^x {{\rm e}^{y^2 } {\rm d}y}  = \frac{x}{2}\int_0^{1/2} {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - x^2 s} }}{{\sqrt {1 - s} }}{\rm d}s}  + \mathcal{O}(x\,{\rm e}^{ - x^2 /2} ).
$$
For $|s|<1$, we can expand $\frac{{\rm 1}}{{\sqrt {1 - s} }}$ as a series:
$$
\frac{{\rm 1}}{{\sqrt {1 - s} }} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(2n)!}}{{2^{2n} n!}}\frac{{s^n }}{{n!}}} .
$$
Using Watson's lemma, we get
$$
\int_0^{1/2} {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - x^2 s} }}{{\sqrt {1 - s} }}{\rm d}s}  \sim \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(2n)!}}{{2^{2n} n!}}\frac{1}{{x^{2n + 2} }}} 
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. Therefore,
$$
{\rm e}^{ - x^2 } \int_0^x {{\rm e}^{y^2 } {\rm d}y}  \sim \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(2n)!}}{{2^{2n + 1} n!}}\frac{1}{{x^{2n+1} }}} 
$$
as $x\to+\infty$.

I do not remember where and when I saw an interesting probabilitic approach for the generation of this unusual series expansion.
It was based on $X\sim\mathcal N(\sqrt 2,\frac 1 {x^2})$ and the calculation of the expected value of $\mathsf EX^{-1}$ using Cauchy principal value. Then a few series expansions were leading to
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2x\sqrt \pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{x^{2k}}$$ which is your expression.
